# GLIBCXX_3.4.9 not found when running ffmpeg from php in lampp server

Tags: php, c++, c, linux, ffmpeg

I've written a php program which creates a video from sequence of images using ffmpeg.

```
<?php
    $res = shell_exec("ffmpeg -framerate 50 -i image/image%d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4 2>&1");
    echo "$res";
```

When I run it,

it says `GLIBCXX_3.4.15` , `GLIBCXX_3.4.9` , `GLIBCXX_3.4.11` **not found**.

> ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not
>
> found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0) ffmpeg:
>
> /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found
>
> (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.3) ffmpeg:
>
> /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found
>
> (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4) ffmpeg:
>
> /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found
>
> (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4)

But from the terminal, `ffmpeg -framerate 50 -i image/image%d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4` command works fine. **Why php can't find the libraries** while from the terminal it works fine? and what should I do to fix the problem in php? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: no. >>> @victorFerreira

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I also got similar problem while executing the ffmpeg command from PHP script. I found the solution by executing the following command from the terminal. I am pasting that command here so somebody get help from this.

```
sudo mv /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6.orig
```

Now just run your php script, hope that will work.

Comment: On the time I posted this question, I was not using linux, I was using xampp inside windows. So I couldn't try your suggestion. But I'm marking this as correct answer as this is the most helpful answer regarding this issue so far.

Comment: I have tried this but now the problem was my php script is just loading.

Answer (score 0):

If u have tried all the above methods(change name to .orig/_old, copy newer version to the lib folder, change LD_LIBRARY_PATH in xampp),

but still failed to solve this problem. Try this trick which worked for me finally:

1.add below line in your PHP file.

```
var_dump(shell_exec("whoami"));
```

you can find the username in your browser after clicking the url related to your PHP file

2.in your terminal

```
sudo vim /ect/sudoers

#in vim editor, add this line in your sudoers file
"username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"
#change username to that found in step one
```

3.change the exec cmd in your PHP file to

```
exec("sudo python3 urfilename.py")
```

The main reason for your problem maybe the root permission, so by changing your sudoers file, the error might be tackled.