# Nodejs returns errors if I try to execute it with PHP's shell_exec() function

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, linux, xampp

I'm using Arch Linux with XAMPP and I tried to execute a nodejs script with php:

```
$ret = shell_exec($command .' 2>&1');
die($ret);
```

$command contains the name of the JS-Skript

I got this output:

```
node: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by node) 
node: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by node) 
node: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by node) 
node: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.64) 
node: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.64)
```

Can anyone help me? gcc-libs is installed

Renaming /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6 to /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6.orig like in [GLIBCXX_3.4.9 not found when running ffmpeg from php in lampp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353604/glibcxx-3-4-9-not-found-when-running-ffmpeg-from-php-in-lampp-server) does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GLIBCXX\_3.4.9 not found when running ffmpeg from php in lampp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353604/glibcxx-3-4-9-not-found-when-running-ffmpeg-from-php-in-lampp-server)

Comment: I tried this already and it didn't work I edited my question

Comment: Update your libstdc++ version.

Comment: I tried this already too